# Обработка больших данных с помощью Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Есть база данных около 500000 записей. Я ее вывел, через jquery datatables, на вебморду.

Выглядит так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я делаю фильтры для этой таблицы. Но ее нужно лимитить при поиске, иначе виснет база, начинает обрабатывать запрос очень долго. Именно когда делаю Count() результатов.

Поэтому логичнее делать лимит, отрабатывает быстрее. Сделал к примеру 5000 записей, но незнаю как сделать проверку, если к примеру в результате запроса будет больше 5000 записей, то брать только 5000 иначе показывать необходимый результат. Подскажите как.

Вот мой код, который есть сейчас

```
public class ResultSet
{


    public int Count(List<string> columnFilters)
    {
        if (!columnFilters.All(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
        {
            return 5000;
        }
        using (OwlEntities dc = new OwlEntities())
        {
            return dc.books.OrderBy(x => x.id).Count();
        }

    }

    public List<books> FilterResult(List<string> columnFilters, int start, int length)
    {

        string book_select = columnFilters[2];
        string book_name = columnFilters[3];




        List<books> result = null;
        if (!columnFilters.All(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
        {
            using (OwlEntities dc = new OwlEntities())
            {
                result = dc.books.OrderBy(x => x.id).Where(x => x.name == book_name.ToLower()).Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (OwlEntities dc = new OwlEntities())
            {
                result = dc.books.OrderBy(x => x.id).Where(x => x.id > start).Take(length).ToList();
            }

        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Несколько ремарок. Проверьте, что у вас есть необходимые индексы. Используйте `AsNoTracking` для запросов на чтение. Сравнение строк на серверной стороне уже и так case insensitive, незачем ToLower вызывать. Изучите, как часто делаются вставки в таблицу и проверьте, как часто пересоздаётся статистика.

Comment: У вас применяются `Skip` и `Take` - это правильный подход. Я не пойму, какие ещё ограничения нужны? Если указано `Take(5000)`, то откуда там возьмётся больше пяти тысяч?

Comment: @a-k Индексы стоят но запросы типа содержит или начинается все равно срабатывают очень долго. Чем AsNoTracking лучше обычного запроса?

Comment: Нужно убрать `OrderBy` из метода `Count`. Для чего сортировать элементы, если нужно просто подсчитать их количество?

Comment: @alexander-petrov Так сейчас получается если даже результат меньше 5000, то он все равно покажет 5000 и таблица будет врать, что записей 5000 , а на деле их к примеру  20. А мне нужно сделать проверку больше 5000 записей в ответе или нет, не запрашивая полный Count(), просто нем таблица виснет

Comment: datatables через ajax ?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd Да через ajax